# Use a filter in facet.range query?

Tags: solr, solrj

```
solrQuery.set("rows", 0);
    solrQuery.set("facet", true);
    solrQuery.set("facet.range", "logtime");
    solrQuery.set("facet.range.start", from);
    solrQuery.set("facet.range.end", to);
    solrQuery.set("facet.range.gap", unit);
    solrQuery.set("facet.mincount", 0);
```

here logtime is a date type

I am thinking of using facet.range.method but I don't know the syntax of it.
Can anyone give example for facet.range.method.
Thanks in advance